# How to fix Mockito Invalid use of argument matchers error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am trying to use Mockito to mock a method, however, I keep getting errors. I have tried to set up Mockito with the spring annotations

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class CPEServiceInvokerImplNewTests {

```
@InjectMocks
CPEServiceInvokerImpl cPEServiceInvokerImpl;
```

and then I use this Mockito call -

```
ExtensionWebClientUtil extensionWebClientUtil = Mockito.mock(ExtensionWebClientUtil.class);
Mockito.when(extensionWebClientUtil.postXMLExchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(),
                Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.any());
```

To try and mock this method -

```
public ResponseEntity<String> postXMLExchange(String restBaseUrl, String endPoint, String jsonBody, Boolean authTokenRequired,String subsKey) ;
```

I get this error -

```
Exception in CPE response org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
5 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.retail.store.basket.extn.service.CPEServiceInvokerImplNewTests.test_JUnit(CPEServiceInvokerImplNewTests.java:61)
```

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

Answer (score 0):

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html :

> Again, note that @InjectMocks will only inject mocks/spies created using the @Spy or @Mock annotation.

So your code should look like this:

```
@Mock
ExtensionWebClientUtil extensionWebClientUtil;

@InjectMocks
CPEServiceInvokerImpl cPEServiceInvokerImpl;

...

Mockito.when(extensionWebClientUtil.postXMLExchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(),
                Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: @InjectMocks
CPEServiceInvokerImpl cPEServiceInvokerImpl;   are already there in the code. But the code is not working

Comment: What about the `@Mock
ExtensionWebClientUtil extensionWebClientUtil` part?